# C# run time error

Tags: c#

can any one please tell me why this program is giving Run time error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
  at System.Int64.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Myclass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
  at System.Int64.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Myclass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

for code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
    long t = Int64.Parse(test);
    while (t > 0)
    {
        t--;
        string res = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        long n = Int64.Parse(res);
        Console.WriteLine(n);
        long ans = n * 8;
        if (n > 1)
            ans = ans + (n - 1) * 6;
        Console.WriteLine(ans);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

and for input:

```
2
1 2
```

Refer to http://ideone.com/beklvQ.

Comment: What exactly exception? For example, `Int64.Parse(test)` in your code will raise `FormatException` is you will enter letter not digit.

Comment: What part of "Input string was not in the correct format" didn't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to handle users entering strings that don't correctly parse to an Int64 and report an error if that happens.

```
        var test = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        long t;
        if (Int64.TryParse(test, out t))
        {
            while (t > 0)
            {
                t--;
                var res = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                var n = Int64.Parse(res);
                Console.WriteLine(n);
                var ans = n*8;
                if (n > 1)
                {
                    ans = ans + (n - 1)*6;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(ans);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid argument {0} entered.", test);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
Console.ReadLine().Trim()
```

you have `res` value of `"1 2"` which is not correct long for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In normal scenario your code will work right, But if you type except of numbers, it will give a run-time error because of converting `string` to `long`.

You can use TryParse() method instead of Parse():

```
long n;
if (Int64.TryParse(res, out n) )
    // Your proper action
```

After your edit:
`Parse()` method can not convert "1 2" to `long`, it contains `space` between numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
        long t = 0;
        bool test = Int64.TryParse(p, out t);

        if(!test)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Wrong String format");
           return;
        }

        while (t > 0)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Write it like this, you are trying to Parse to long string which is not long. Because of that you have this exception. If you write it like this your are checking first if this is possible, if the converting to long is successful your values is written in t, if not `test` return false and you are showing error message.